training data of stable cascade vs stable diffusion
So according to this: https://waxy.org/2022/08/exploring-12-million-of-the-images-used-to-train-stable-diffusions-image-generator/
Stable Diffusion was trained on data from CommonCrawler. I believe Stable Cascade was trained using the same source but where can I find more detailed info on the data that was used for training the Cascade model? Looking for details like

amount of data
sites used

etc
